# I want to convert attributes to elements in Strong-SOAP xmlToJson

Tags: json, node.js, strong-soap

I'm using [strong-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap) node.js module to convert XML string to JSON string: [xmlHandler.xmlToJson()](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap/blob/2eadad32f0c82b4bbdc0b780328b0e2a7386e51c/example/xml2json.js)

but XML from SOAP have in tag attributes and they are converted from [strong-soap](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap) to JSON element with key $attributes like:

```
{"fuelStation":{
"$attributes":{"id":"62611","lastUpdate":"2017-05-17T19:01:14.745Z","provider":"mdm"},
"location": ...
```

How can I remove this $attributes key to have JSON string like:

```
{"fuelStation":{
    "id":"62611","lastUpdate":"2017-05-17T19:01:14.745Z","provider":"mdm",
    "location": ...
```

I can only remove the whole $attributes but this is not my goal:

```
const root = xmlHandler.xmlToJson(null, xmlString, null);
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(root.Body.GetFuelStationsResponse, function replacer(key, value) {
                    return key !== '$attributes' ? value: undefined;
                });
```

Can I convert attributes into JSON properties using strong-soap xmlToJson or with JSON.stringify replacer function?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with JSON.stringify:

```
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(root.Body.GetFuelStationsResponse, function replacer(key, value) {
                if(value !== null && typeof value === 'object' && '$attributes' in value){
                    for(const k in value.$attributes) value[k]=value.$attributes[k];
                    value.$attributes = undefined;
                }
                return value;
            });
```